# why does the same code work on jupyter and fail on moodle

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, moodle

[this is the code I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs8Kr.png)

```
def q4():
    s=input("Enter the string: ")
    return s[::-1]

print(q4())
```

[image: this is the result]
thanks in advance!

I tried this code on jupyter and it worked but when i switched to moodle it just failed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You're calling the function but not printing the result. Jupyter is a REPL, it prints the results automatically. But this doesn't happen in scripts. Use `print(qf4())`

Comment: thank you for replying, I just edit my code and post it on the question. However, I got this message from moodle:  
Enter the string: ab
ba
Enter the string:
***Error***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 14, in <module>
    q4()
  File "__tester__.python3", line 9, in q4
    s=input("Enter the string: ")
  File "__tester__.python3", line 3, in input
    s = __saved_input__(prompt)
EOFError: EOF when reading a line